# How do I enable scroll arrows for large number of items in UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to use a UISegmentedControl to present several options for interacting with the screen. However I have a larger number of items than the width of the screen on an iPhone device. How do I enable scroll arrows on the UISegmentedControl to scroll through the items as seen is some apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support for arrows and scrolling in `UISegmentedControl`.  You need to put in arrow segments yourself and change the segments when the arrow segments are clicked.